# copying / cloing neo4django model object

Tags: django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I was wondering whether there was a smart way to create an exact clone of a node in neo4django without having to copy every property and relationship manually.

```
p = Person.create(name="John Doe")
p.connect(...)

new_p = p
```

won't work, as `new_p` won't be a clone (a new, individual node with same content), but rather a different pointer to the same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So do you need a new node in the graph, or a copy of the Django model?

To create a copy with the same properties (but not the same relationships) and a new in-graph node, you could try something like

```
p = Person.objects.create(name="John Doe")
p2 = Person.objects.create(**p.node.properties)
```

Doing the same thing with relationships is a little more difficult, but I've done it in the past and can write up a gist if that's what you need. Alternatively, this could also all be done in Gremlin or Cypher (with neo4django's helper functions) if that's a better fit, eg

```
from neo4django.db import connection
p = Person._neo4j_instance(connection.gremlin('results=<some code that yields a copied node>'))
```

If you just need a copy of the Django model that's a different Python object (but still attached to the same node) you might try

```
>>> p = Person.objects.create(name="John Doe")
>>> p2 = Person.from_model(p)
>>> print p2.name
John Doe
```

HTH!

EDIT:

How could I have forgotten- there's an included convenience method for this!

```
>>> john = Person.objects.create(name="John Doe")
>>> john_2 = john.copy_model()
>>> john.name == john_2.name
True
```

Relationships and properties are all copied, though the returned model is unsaved- they don't share a node in the graph.

Sorry about the run around, maybe this will be a little easier.

Comment: Actually I wanted _eventually_ a new node in the graph. However, I want to edit (some of) the properties (and relationships) before saving the new node.

Comment: So your first suggestion (**p.node.properties) helps. I would appreciate the offered Gist for properties (or can it more ore less be achieved with a for...in loop?)

Comment: It's basically a loop over fields in the `Person._meta.fields` list. Fields that are a subclass of `neo4django.db.models.relationships.MultipleNodes` and `SingleNode` are the fields for the many and one side of a relationship, and you can get things like their name. I'll post a gist if that isn't clear enough- I'd be surprised if it is ha.